# Random failures while working with Rest Assured

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, api, rest-assured

My tests are written and cater on certain requests but same Suite on running gives errors on different tests
for example I have methods A,B,C,D,E
It will pass A, B and D but will fail C and E
Next time it will pass A, C, D, E but will fail B

This has been throughout my test
Can anyone suggest a solution? I want to use Wait for responses as I believe maybe it moves on to next step before getting full response. I dont want to use Thread.sleep() as its not a good practice
Can anyone suggest something? Also, how to work with Wait command of Rest Assured

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility.

Example below from documentation:

```
@Test
public void updatesCustomerStatus() throws Exception {
    // Publish an asynchronous event:
    publishEvent(updateCustomerStatusEvent);
    // Awaitility lets you wait until the asynchronous operation completes:
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(customerStatusIsUpdated());
    ...
}
```